# calculating line regression paramters in python

Tags: python, linear-regression

Hi guys im trying to calculate line regression parameters using these calculations. But the code of written isnt giving me the output I want and I really dont know why. I think I have it right, can anyone see any obvious mistakes that im missing ? thanks in advance

[image]

```
def BeOne(x,y):
for i in x:
    list.append(i**2)
B1 = ((sum([a * b for a, b in zip(x, y)]))-(len(x)*(mean(x))*
     (mean(y))))/((sum( i**2 for i in x))-(len(x)*(mean(list))))
return B1

def BeZero(x,y,B1):
    B0 = mean(y) - (B1 * mean(x))
    return B0
```

Comment: n has to be a length of x list not len(x) + len(y).

Comment: `list.append(i**2)` Don't you think this line has a problem? Unless you named a variable `list` which is same as inviting errors.

Comment: in my notes it says n is the number of items in each set x and y. Thats why i did the length of x + y. I just made an empty list and then put the values squared in there to then get the mean. Thats the only way I could think of doing it.

Comment: You have just as many x values as y values, so `n = len(x)`. And `sum(x)*sum(y)` is nowhere near the sum over the product `x * y`.

Comment: yeah i see that sum(x)*sum(y), isnt right. I replaced it with (sum(a *b for a, b in zip(x,y))) When changing to n = len(x) though i get a zerodivision error though